# c++ Google test (gtest): how to create custom asserts and expects?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I am using **gtest** to create unit tests to my c++ program. In my tests I have to write a lot of checks like this:

```
ASSERT_TRUE(myObject.IsValid());
EXPECT_EQ(myObject.GetSomeAttribute(), expectedValue);
```

I have to write both checks because if I omit the `ASSERT_TRUE` and `myObject` happened to be not valid, than `myObject.GetSomeAttributre()` call crashes. That's not good even in tests.

What I want is to write something like:

```
EXPECT_XXX_EQ(myObject.GetSomeAttribute(), expectedValue);
```

This line of code should do approximately the same as the original two lines (with optional bonus that if `myObject` is not valid, this will be reported, `GetSomeAttribute()` would not be called, but the test will continue running).

How can I write such custom assert/expect?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom C++ assert macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5252375/custom-c-assert-macro)

Comment: Why not fix your code to check that the object is valid in the call to getattribute?

Comment: @stark Two reasons: 1. I can't modify GetSomeAttribute() 2. Even if I could, the best this method could do is to die if called for invalid object.

Comment: @Eddge Not a duplicate; googletest asserts are very different from the standard c++ asserts

Comment: Did you not read [the documentation](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/AdvancedGuide.md#using-a-function-that-returns-an-assertionresult)?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120742/custom-expect-near-macro-in-google-test

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [Advanced Guide](https://google.github.io/googletest/advanced.html), we can see that there are a couple ways we could do this.

The easiest way is by [using assertions in a subroutine](https://google.github.io/googletest/advanced.html#using-assertions-in-sub-routines):

```
template<typename T>
void AssertAttributeEquals(MyObject const& obj, T value) {
    ASSERT_TRUE(obj.IsValid());
    // googletest has the assumption that you put the
    // expected value first
    EXPECT_EQ(value, obj.GetAttribute());
}
```

And you can call it like so:

```
AssertAttributeEquals(myObject, expectedValue);
```

Although you may want to use [`SCOPED_TRACE`](https://google.github.io/googletest/advanced.html#adding-traces-to-assertions) to get a better message on failure:

```
{
    SCOPED_TRACE("whatever message you want");
    AssertAttributeEquals(myObject, expectedValue);
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can [use a function that returns an `AssertionResult`](https://google.github.io/googletest/advanced.html#using-a-function-that-returns-an-assertionresult):

```
template<typename T>
::testing::AssertionResult AttributeEquals(MyObject const& obj, T value) {
    if (!obj.IsValid()) {
        // If MyObject is streamable, then we probably want to include it
        // in the error message.
        return ::testing::AssertionFailure() << obj << " is not valid";
    }
    auto attr = obj.GetAttribute();

    if (attr == value) {
        return ::testing::AssertionSuccess();
    } else {
        return ::testing::AssertionFailure() << attr << " not equal to " << value;
    }
}
```

This can be used like so:

```
EXPECT_TRUE(AttributeEquals(myObject, expectedValue));
```

This second technique has the benefit of producing nice error messages even if you don't use `SCOPED_TRACE`

Comment: The downside with functions is that in case of failure the reported source line is inside the function and not where the function is called. This makes it harder to see where exactly things failed.

Comment: The `SCOPED_TRACE` can help but is extra code one has to write. (had to create a new comment as I didn't edit quickly enough)

Answer (score 0):

I could remove the need to duplicate all the calls to `SCOPED_TRACE("...")` by using macros. Now you can use the normal GTEST assertions inside a void function and use the macro in your tests:

**test_common.h:**

```cpp
inline void AssertTokenTypesEqual__(const std::string& code, std::vector<TokenType> expectedTokens)
{
    auto tokens = Tokenize(code);

    ASSERT_EQ(tokens.size(), expectedTokens.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.size(); ++i) {
        ASSERT_EQ(expectedTokens[i], tokens[i].type);
    }
}

#define ASSERT_TOKEN_TYPES_EQUAL(code__, expectedTokens__)  \
    SCOPED_TRACE("Tokenization didn't match expectations"); \
    AssertTokenTypesEqual__(code__, expectedTokens__)
```

**my-test.cpp:**

```cpp
TEST(TokenizerTest, Works) {
   auto code = "void func();";

   auto expectedTokens = {...}; // <- you might need to create variables of your values outside the assertion.

   ASSERT_TOKEN_TYPES_EQUAL(code, expectedTokens);
}
```